# python apply function but ignore columns if not in index

Tags: python, pandas, function, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have 3 dataframes each with at least 1 column that needs to be converted to `datetime64`.

```
times = ['time1','time2','time3']
```

I have this function -

```
def cols_to_datetime(df, cols=None):
    if not cols:
        
        cols = times
    df[cols] = df[cols].astype('datetime64')
    return df
```

And then run 3 dfs through this, but df3 only has `time1`. How can I keep all three time columns but ignore the index error if one of the dfs does not have all of the time columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
time_cols = ['time1', 'time2', 'time3']
def cols_to_datetime(df, cols=None):
    if not cols:
        # only take the column names that are present in df.columns
        cols = [tcol for tcol in time_cols if tcol in df.columns]
    df[cols] = df[cols].astype('datetime64')
    return df
```